# Setting Simple Sitemap Values Programmatically not reflected in form

Tags: 8, xml-sitemap

I'm trying to set some Simple Sitemap settings programmatically. I'm using the following to set whether or not a specific node is indexed:

`\Drupal::service('simple_sitemap.generator')->setEntityInstanceSettings('node', $node->get('nid')->value, ['index' => FALSE]);`

This works fine and I was able to see the results reflected in my sitemap. However, this is only reflected in the "Simple Sitemap" form of that node if the value is set to `TRUE`. If `FALSE` neither radio button is selected.

This is confusing to others who are editing the site. How can I get this reflected in the form?

[image: Empty form]

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out, but in case anyone else runs into this. The documentation in the readme.md file shows the following format the settings:

`setBundleSettings('node', 'page', ['index' => TRUE, 'priority' = 0.5])`

Instead of using `TRUE/FALSE` I changed the index setting to `0/1` and this was successfully reflected in the form as expected.

`\Drupal::service('simple_sitemap.generator')->setEntityInstanceSettings('node', $node->get('nid')->value, ['index' => 0]);`

Comment: In case people have trouble with this, the service has since been updated and is now `simple_sitemap.entity_manager`. So the result would be instead:

\Drupal::service('simple_sitemap.entity_manager')->setEntityInstanceSettings('node', $node->get('nid')->value, ['index' => 0]);

Answer (score 0):

I have [created an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap/issues/2968979) for you on drupal.org and fixed it. Please use the boolean values when using the API instead of the integers.

The fix along with many other [improvements](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/simple_sitemap?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=8.x-3.x-dev&component=All) can be found in branch [3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap/releases/8.x-3.x-dev).